# Maven dependency on a web application

Tags: web-applications, maven, dependencies

I just thought of the dependency system of maven and I asked myself, wether it is possible to have a dependency on a web application(*.war file)?
I would like to maintain a core module of the application as a normal web application. The more specific implementations will use the core as dependency and extend it.

For example, I have the following:

1. Core.war // Backend
2. ConcreteProject1.war // Frontend for customer 1
3. ConcreteProject2.war // Frontend for customer 2

The concrete project should now have a dependency on the Core.war and include all web pages, other resources, source files, etc. but if a file with the same name, within the context path, exists, the concrete project should override the original one. It would be even more nice if it was possible to merge such files! Just think of e.g. a log config file which would be merged with the custom one for special handling for the client. There are many other use cases where it would be really usefull.

Could anyone give me a hint on what i can do to get such a behaviour in my build process?

Comment: I just realized that it really works! I have tested the dependency now, but is it also possible to define something like a merge for some files? database.properties would just need username, password etc. but not all the config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something along these lines...

Say you have two modules - core and web-module1 and that you need to have them assembled in a war in the end.

The core's POM:

```
<project>

    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>false</archiveClasses>
                    <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>

                    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/mywebapp</webappDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The POM of module which depends on the core:

```
<project>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-module1</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>

                    <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/web.xml</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </overlay>
                    </overlays>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The assembly:

```
<project>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-assembly</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>false</archiveClasses>
                    <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>

                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>

                    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/mywebapp</webappDirectory>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>

                    <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/web.xml</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </overlay>
                    </overlays>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-module1</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks really nice. Is there also a method to merge files, like configs and so on?

Comment: Well, there are certain ways, but I avoid doing that. As far as I know you can use the cargo plugin, or something like that. What I normally do is I have the resources within the respective module and they only concern the settings for the module. In the assembly I have the full settings. For example for a web.xml.